# Webservice não aceita arquivo xml

Tags: c#

Estou gerando um XML, e envio para `webservice`, e ele sempre me retorna o mesmo erro, Erro 500, porém este erro é mto vago, consegui ter o seguinte retorno no erro:

> :ServerCould not parse content
>   type:javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected parameter name, got
>   "/"

Segue como estou tentando enviar:

```
public static MemoryStream stringToStream(string dados)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream;
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[dados.Length];
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(dados);
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return memoryStream;
    }

    private void montaEnvelope(HttpWebRequest webRequest, XmlDocument document, string numero)
    {
        string soapEnvelope = string.Empty;


        //soapEnvelope += "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.issweb.fiorilli.com.br/\" xmlns:xd=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">";
        soapEnvelope += "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:e=\"http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws\">";
        //soapEnvelope += "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:gerarNfse>";
        soapEnvelope += "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><e:gerarNfse><nfseCabecMsg>";
        soapEnvelope += "<cabecalho xmlns=\"http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws\" versao=\"2.02\"><versaoDados>2.02</versaoDados></cabecalho></nfseCabecMsg><nfseDadosMsg>";

           soapEnvelope += document.LastChild.OuterXml.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", string.Empty);
        //soapEnvelope += "<username>01001001000113</username><password>123456</password></ws:gerarNfse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        soapEnvelope += "</nfseDadosMsg></e:gerarNfse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        //soapEnvelope += "</e:gerarNfse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        MemoryStream stream = stringToStream(soapEnvelope);
        webRequest.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        stream.WriteTo(requestStream);

        document.LoadXml(soapEnvelope);
        document.PreserveWhitespace = false;

        document.Save(@"E:\\NFSe-" + "RPS" + numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml");
        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("E:\\NFSe-" + "RPS" + numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml");
        doc.Save("E:\\NFSe-" + "RPS" + numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml", System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);


        this.XmlDocNFSe = document;
    }

    private static string getSoapResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        string soapResult = string.Empty;

        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        xmlResponse.LoadXml(soapResult);
        XmlNode responseNode = xmlResponse.LastChild.LastChild.FirstChild;

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlResponse.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd");
        XmlNode codigo = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Codigo", ns);
        XmlNode mensagem = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Mensagem", ns);
        XmlNode correcao = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Correcao", ns);
        XmlNode numero = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Numero", ns);
        XmlNode codigoVerificacao = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:CodigoVerificacao", ns);
        XmlNode data = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:DataEmissao", ns);
        XmlNode outras = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:Outras", ns);
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlResponse.SelectNodes("//ns2:InfNfse", ns))
        {
            Id = (node.Attributes["Id"].Value);
        }
        try
        {
            cod = codigo.InnerText;
            msgm = mensagem.InnerText;
            cor = correcao.InnerText;
        }
        catch
        {
            Numero = numero.InnerText;
            CodigoVerificacao = codigoVerificacao.InnerText;
        }
        return responseNode.InnerXml;

    }

    private static HttpWebRequest getWebRequest(string url, string method)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Timeout = 100000;
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", method);
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; //charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }


private string post(string url, string method, string xml, X509Certificate2 certificate, string numero)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xml);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = getWebRequest(url, method);
            webRequest.Proxy = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
            Uri myUri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.3:3128");
            myProxy.Address = myUri;
            myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
            webRequest.Proxy = myProxy;
            webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            montaEnvelope(webRequest, doc, numero);
            return getSoapResponse(webRequest);
        }

        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
            using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                msgm = reader.ReadToEnd();
                cod = "Erro";
            }
            return msgm;
        }
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    return null;
        //}
    }
```

Não consigo ter outro retorno, o que estou fazendo de errado ?
Vou colocar o xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:e="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body><e:gerarNfse><nfseCabecMsg><cabecalho xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws" versao="2.02"><versaoDados>2.02</versaoDados></cabecalho></nfseCabecMsg><nfseDadosMsg><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:e="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body><e:gerarNfse><nfseCabecMsg><cabecalho xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws" versao="2.02"><versaoDados>2.02</versaoDados></cabecalho></nfseCabecMsg><nfseDadosMsg><GerarNfseEnvio xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"><Rps><InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico Id="RPS000000000008963"><Rps><IdentificacaoRps><Numero>8963</Numero><Serie>999</Serie><Tipo>1</Tipo></IdentificacaoRps><DataEmissao>2018-12-17</DataEmissao><Status>1</Status></Rps><Competencia>2018-12-17</Competencia><Servico><Valores><ValorServicos>29</ValorServicos><ValorDeducoes>0.00</ValorDeducoes><ValorIss>0.87</ValorIss><Aliquota>3</Aliquota><DescontoIncondicionado>0</DescontoIncondicionado><DescontoCondicionado>0</DescontoCondicionado></Valores><IssRetido>2</IssRetido><ItemListaServico>0107</ItemListaServico><Discriminacao>Descricao 62</Discriminacao><CodigoMunicipio>0</CodigoMunicipio><ExigibilidadeISS>1</ExigibilidadeISS><MunicipioIncidencia>3107109</MunicipioIncidencia></Servico><Prestador><CpfCnpj><Cnpj>07652413000108</Cnpj></CpfCnpj><InscricaoMunicipal>5467630</InscricaoMunicipal></Prestador><Tomador><IdentificacaoTomador><CpfCnpj><Cpf>08297163008</Cpf></CpfCnpj></IdentificacaoTomador><RazaoSocial>Teste Mariana</RazaoSocial><Endereco><Endereco>RUA JARBAS PIMENTA</Endereco><Numero>514</Numero><Complemento>complemento cobrancaaeAaO</Complemento><Bairro>NOVA ERA</Bairro><CodigoMunicipio>3504800</CodigoMunicipio><Uf>SP</Uf><Cep>37170000</Cep></Endereco><Contato><Telefone>3538511836</Telefone><Email>marianac_costa@live.com</Email></Contato></Tomador><RegimeEspecialTributacao>1</RegimeEspecialTributacao><OptanteSimplesNacional>1</OptanteSimplesNacional><IncentivoFiscal>1</IncentivoFiscal></InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI="#RPS000000000008963"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>XXvtJY4dUMxIcMWw+yUbSHNkfUE=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>XoWPqLsjsojfsjFs6ZXXc/bGb0Vy7EcFc5QOe/ja88Nhi3dKV76LCogTz4GjYD0tByovmXixCfez3sSuyijeTTryj8vTAsQKBgDj/PFD08W/fJsE+zmOPxYCqAE2m2yBZD++afT3DOYDqYxkwGpF/o5YSaMAA3G1ilUvfPUqlq3VmT6NIiD1ffvZsh02TpTZMz35JTb0rptX/5tsswAaWJTwrMAljY23iibD4Pkl+fGXFKDHXWdHv1XSiSvSSK3Niost02OxqfxwWQedspFGgXnmpx3fee7qSyHPKavZu64KUvy8jNDKJkUNYg/V/DAe3ShQPbZrbUW6KemN6BM76A==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></Rps></GerarNfseEnvio></nfseDadosMsg></e:gerarNfse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope></nfseDadosMsg></e:gerarNfse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Isso está certo ? myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("desenvolvimento02", "*Ec16&p7D+");
            myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: Tá sim, na verdade esta linha é ignorada, pq eu pego as informações default. @VictorLaio retirei ela

Answer (score 1):

Está fazendo complicado demais para usar esse serviço. Se me permite, confira a documentação em: https://e-gov.betha.com.br/e-nota-test/ambienteteste.faces. Lá tem os manuais e exemplos dos xmls esperados.

Segue uma nova abordagem para consumir esse serviço:

Adicione a referência do serviço no visual studio para o wsdl:
http://e-gov.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws/nfseWS?wsdl

No `Soluction Explorer` clique com o botão direito no projeto e vá em `Add` em seguida em `Service Reference`.
Em `Address` informe a URL do WSDL e clique em `Go`.
Em `Namespace` informe o nome desejado. `Ex.: wsNfse`
Clique em `OK`.

Após isso, veja o exemplo abaixo de como chamar o webservice:
(obs: é claro que está simplificado para teste, demonstrando o xml esperado conforme a documentação.)

```
using (var cli = new wsNfse.NfseWSClient())
            {
                string _nfseCabecMsg = $@"
                     < cabecalho xmlns = ""http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"" versao = ""2.02"" >< versaoDados > 2.02 </ versaoDados ></ cabecalho >
                    ";
                string _nfseDadosMsg = $@"
                    <GerarNfseEnvio xmlns = ""http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws"">
                        <Rps>
                            <InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico  Id=""lote"">
                                <Rps>
                                    <IdentificacaoRps>
                                        <Numero></Numero>
                                        <Serie></Serie>
                                        <Tipo></Tipo>
                                    </IdentificacaoRps>
                                    <DataEmissao></DataEmissao>
                                    <Status></Status>
                                    <RpsSubstituido>
                                        <Numero></Numero>
                                        <Serie></Serie>
                                        <Tipo></Tipo>
                                    </RpsSubstituido>
                                </Rps>
                                <Competencia></Competencia>
                                <Servico>
                                    <Valores>
                                        <ValorServicos></ValorServicos>
                                        <ValorDeducoes></ValorDeducoes>
                                        <ValorPis></ValorPis>
                                        <ValorCofins></ValorCofins>
                                        <ValorInss></ValorInss>
                                        <ValorIr></ValorIr>
                                        <ValorCsll></ValorCsll>
                                        <OutrasRetencoes></OutrasRetencoes>
                                        <ValorIss></ValorIss>
                                        <Aliquota></Aliquota>
                                        <DescontoIncondicionado></DescontoIncondicionado>
                                        <DescontoCondicionado></DescontoCondicionado>   
                                    </Valores>
                                    <IssRetido></IssRetido>
                                    <ResponsavelRetencao></ResponsavelRetencao>
                                    <ItemListaServico></ItemListaServico>
                                    <CodigoCnae></CodigoCnae>
                                    <CodigoTributacaoMunicipio></CodigoTributacaoMunicipio>
                                    <Discriminacao></Discriminacao>
                                    <CodigoMunicipio></CodigoMunicipio>
                                    <CodigoPais></CodigoPais>
                                    <ExigibilidadeIss></ExigibilidadeIss>
                                    <MunicipioIncidencia></MunicipioIncidencia>
                                    <NumeroProcesso></NumeroProcesso>
                                </Servico>
                                <Prestador>
                                    <CpfCnpj>
                                        <Cnpj></Cnpj>
                                    </CpfCnpj>
                                    <InscricaoMunicipal></InscricaoMunicipal>
                                </Prestador>
                                <Tomador>
                                    <IdentificacaoTomador>
                                        <CpfCnpj>
                                            <Cnpj></Cnpj>
                                        </CpfCnpj>
                                        <InscricaoMunicipal></InscricaoMunicipal>               
                                    </IdentificacaoTomador>
                                    <RazaoSocial></RazaoSocial>
                                    <Endereco>
                                        <Endereco></Endereco>
                                        <Numero></Numero>
                                        <Complemento></Complemento>
                                        <Bairro></Bairro>
                                        <CodigoMunicipio></CodigoMunicipio>
                                        <Uf></Uf>
                                        <CodigoPais></CodigoPais>
                                        <Cep></Cep>
                                    </Endereco>
                                    <Contato>
                                        <Telefone></Telefone>
                                        <Email></Email>
                                    </Contato>
                                </Tomador>
                                <Intermediario>
                                    <IdentificacaoIntermediario>
                                        <CpfCnpj>
                                            <Cnpj></Cnpj>
                                        </CpfCnpj>
                                        <InscricaoMunicipal></InscricaoMunicipal>               
                                    </IdentificacaoIntermediario>
                                    <RazaoSocial></RazaoSocial>
                                </Intermediario>
                                <ConstrucaoCivil>
                                    <CodigoObra></CodigoObra>
                                    <Art></Art>
                                </ConstrucaoCivil>
                                <RegimeEspecialTributacao></RegimeEspecialTributacao>
                                <OptanteSimplesNacional></OptanteSimplesNacional>
                                <IncentivoFiscal></IncentivoFiscal>
                            </InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico>
                        </Rps>
                    </GerarNfseEnvio>
                ";                

                var retorno = cli.GerarNfse(new wsNfse.GerarNfse { nfseCabecMsg = _nfseCabecMsg, nfseDadosMsg = _nfseDadosMsg });
            }
```

Verifique a variável string de retorno!

Poderia também criar classes de acordo com o objetos XML e serializando os objetos para preencher os parâmetros de entrada em string e a string de retorno em objeto.
Segue duas funções úteis para isso:

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializa um objeto para uma string no formato XML apartir do objeto referênciado.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="value">Objeto</param>
/// <example>string xmlString = meuObj.XmlSerialize();</example>
/// <returns>String em formato XML do objeto referênciado</returns>
public static string ToXml<T>(this T value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return string.Empty;

    var xmlserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Deserializa uma string em formato XML em um objeto do tipo especificado.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="value">XML string</param>
/// <example>MinhaClasse obj = xmlString.XmlToObject<MinhaClasse>();</example>
/// <returns>Objeto do tipo especificado</returns>
public static T XmlToObject<T>(this string value)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (StringReader rdr = new StringReader(value))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não consigo add o serviço como referencia, ele somente me retorna erro.

Comment: Consegui resolver, era problema ao gerar o xml mesmo, obrigado.